# In Safari 5.1, how do I disable Top Sites and the caching of thumbnail images of Web pages?

Tags: customization, safari

There were methods for doing this in earlier versions of Safari but I don't know of one that works with 5.1.

The reason I want to do this is that it takes up a great deal of disk space, and I suspect it slows things down on my older, slower Mac running Lion because of all the extra caching going on. I never use the feature anyway.

Here is the link to an earlier question on Ask Different with regard to Safari 5.0.

[How can I disable "Top Sites" in Safari/Webkit completely?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4180/how-can-i-disable-top-sites-in-safari-webkit-completely)

I am creating a new question because apparently any methods that would work for Safari 5.0 will not work for 5.1.

Comment: Haven't found a specific answer, but if you're having performance issues with 5.1, try one of the [WebKit nightlies](http://nightly.webkit.org/). I've switched recently and it improved a lot a of the performance problems introduced with 5.1, and so far haven't seen any problematic bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TinkerTool 4.7](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html), a free utility for system customization, has just added a new feature for Safari 5.1, "Disable storage of preview images for web pages."

[image: TinkerTool]

Answer (score 1):

While not a clean solution and not properly preventing Safari from creating the thumbnails in the first place, this apparently works to keep them from taking up disk space:

```
rm ~/Library/Safari/WebpageIcons.db && ln -s /dev/null ~/Library/Safari/WebpageIcons.db
```

Incidentally, even going to **Safari → Reset Safari**… and ticking **Remove all webpage preview images** will apparently leave this hack intact.

As for Top Sites, there are a few places you can remove it from:

- **Safari → Preferences → General → New windows open with**
- **Safari → Preferences → General → New tabs open with**
- **Safari → Preferences → Bookmarks → Bookmarks bar**

I don't believe the menu item can be removed this easily.