# Closing Safari quickly -- without Webpage Preview Fetcher?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, safari

For the past few months, attempting to close Safari normally (Command-Q) quickly closes open browser windows, but takes forever (~10+ min) to fully close, if it closes at all.

A look at the Activity monitor shows that the sub-process Safari Webpage Preview Fetcher churns away, often at high CPU usage (~50%), for a few minutes, but then it and all other Safari related processes drop to zero CPU, but Safari still will not go away. I am only loading the default set of top sites, i.e. have not specified any particular top sites since the last time I reset Safari a few weeks ago.

This behavior existed for me under Snow Leopard, and has sadly continued after a recent upgrade to Lion. I am now running OSX 10.7.3 with Safari 5.1.3

I can of course force quit, but it would be great to be able to quit normally. I would consider stopping Top Sites all together as is described [in another post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4180/how-can-i-disable-top-sites-in-safari-webkit-completely), but would rather decouple that option from simply getting Safari to quit normally. I am also not sure if the top site disable even works in Lion (and am too new to comment on that thread).

How can I get Safari to close normally?

Update: this behavior is somewhat intermittent. I will try to update this question as I identify possible/reliable triggers. For now it seems opening Safari and running simple Google search doe not cause a slow close.

Comment: Just curious, how long does command-option-Q take?

Comment: Interesting thought. I just looked up command-option-Q to find that it causes a close without remembering last open windows (new on Lion?). I'll do some experimenting.